# How to plot a heatmap image from a NetCDF file in Python Jupyter?

Tags: python, image-processing, jupyter-notebook, heatmap

I have an image from a NetCDF file and it has a type of:

```
holoviews.element.raster.RGB
```

and has a shape as:

```
(512000, 5)
```

This shape might be a little confusing but the max numbers for the shape of the image is:

```
(999, 511)
```

representing the x and y axes of the image.

The question is:

This image is a NIR image and I need to converted it to a heatmap image.

I have looked up ways but none is working and most methods give this error of:

```
NotImplementedError: Iteration on Elements is not supported.
```

Is there a way of plotting this image with a heatmap option ?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you not just want to plot the netCDF itself as a heatmap? I don't understand why you would want to do what you are trying to do

Comment: Thanks, @RobertWilson for the reply. In the netCDF file, there is a key called: image and it has the following shape = (49, 512, 1000). It is a float32 image(wave, x, y). I just could not plot the heatmap image for this kind of image. It has to do with the shape of it, i am guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try plotting this using my ncplot package. This will automatically generate a plot using hvplot from a netCDF file. The code would be as follows:

```
from ncplot import view
view("infile.nc", vars= "image")
```

Comment: Many thanks @RobertWilson . It plotted my image. Are there any options to be chosen like inverting the axes, showing 'jet' version of the image etc ?

Comment: Thanks @NaifAlsalem. The aim of the package is to provide light weight autoplotting. However, it will return an hvplot object, and you can typically modify the plot by passing hvplot arguments to `view` https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/Customization.html. Example `view("infile.nc", legend = False)` will remove the legend.

Comment: Got it. Much obliged @RobertWilson.